# Can this be expressed in terms of Laplace Transform?

Tags: probability-distributions, laplace-transform

I have an expression in the from:

$$\mathbb{P}(H>\theta)=\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-m\theta I)f_I(i){\rm{d}}i$$

Here, $f_I(i)$ is the PDF of random variable $I$.

Let, $\mathcal{L}_I(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f_I(i)$,

How can we express $\mathbb{P}(H>\theta)$ in terms of $\mathcal{L}_I(s)$ when the Laplace transform of $I$ is evaluated at $s=m\theta using the properties of Laplace transform?

Conclusion: I want to express the right hand side of the equation in terms of Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}_I(s)$, wh.ere $\mathcal{L}_I(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f_I(i)$.

Comment: you mean $\int_0^\infty \exp(-m \theta x) f_I(x) dx$ ? if $\mathcal{L}_I(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} f_I(x) dx$ then it is $\mathcal{L}_I(m \theta)$

Comment: @user1952009, thanks for your comment. What do you mean by $\mathcal{L}_I(1)$? I am not a math person. Would you please explain in detail. Why did you use $\mathcal{L}_I(1)$ in place of $\mathcal{L}_I(s)$?

Comment: .... ${}{}{}{}$